# Creating new variable with latest non missing entry in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

I have the following sample data, here 99 is a missing entry.

```
DATA HAVE;
input var2001 var2002 var2003 var2004;
cards;
1 1 99 99
3 99 4 4
99 4 3 99
4 4 99 4
99 99 99 99
;
run;
```

I want to create a new variable 'var_cur' for latest non missing entry. If a variable only has missing entries then the new variables must have '99' as entry.

Desired output

```
Obs       var_cur

1           1

2           4

3           3
4           4

5          99
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why do you have `99` instead of missing?  Why do you have 4 variables in the original and only one in the output?  Why not have the original data in a single variable to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the 99 values to actual missing values then the COALESCE() function can do what you want. Just give it the variables in the reverse order.

```
val_cur = coalesce(of var2004-var2001);
```

It would be much easier if you have a vertical structure to start with and if your missing values were actually coded as missing values.

```
data have;
  row+1;
  do _n_=1 to 4 ;
    input value @ ;
    if value=99 the value =. ;
    output;
  end;
cards;
1 1 99 99
3 99 4 4
99 4 3 99
4 4 99 4
99 99 99 99
;
```

Then you could use the UPDATE statement.

```
data want;
  update have(obs=0) have ;
  by row;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    row    value

 1      1       1
 2      2       4
 3      3       3
 4      4       4
 5      5       .
```

The UPDATE statement is for applying transactions to a dataset.  You need an original dataset and a transaction dataset.  In this case we use an empty verison of the dataset as the original data and all observations as transactions.  Missing values in the transaction dataset mean that no change is requested for that variable. So the result is the last non-missing value for each variable.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in details the UPDATE trick ?

Comment: `UPDATE` is the same as `MERGE` with one caveat -- missing values from the second data set *do not* overwrite any values in the PDV.

Comment: There are more differences between UPDATE and MERGE than that simplistic explanation.